# Congruence of 2 fractions—how to properly rewrite in terms without modulo?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fractions

**EDIT:** Following Theo's comment, the equivalence holds since one can (must) rewrite $1/a$ as $(1+23k)/a$.

---

Provided that $$\frac{1}{25} \equiv \frac{1}{2}\pmod {23}$$
is true, why can I not rewrite it like usually possible?

$$\frac{1}{25}=\frac{1}{2}+23k ~\text{ for }~k \in \mathbb Z$$

$$\implies 2=25+50\cdot23k, \text{which is impossible.}$$

I guess that the factor 50 somehow may be ignored here, but I don't understand how (if at all). What's the clue here?

Comment: Well, the equality is certainly true mod 23...

Comment: Remember $1/2$ in mod $23$ is not literally the fraction; it's the *multiplicative inverse* of $23$. That is, it is the class of numbers $x$ that satisfy $2x \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 23$. In this case, $1/2$ is $12$, since $2 \cdot 12 = 24 \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 23$.

Comment: @TheoBendit That's it, thank you.

Comment: One should never use fraction notation in finite fields. It's too confusional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be careful when considering fractions in modular arithmetic. Was does it mean to write $\frac{1}{25} \equiv \frac{1}{2} \mod 23$ ?

Here are two possible interpretations :

1. You may see that as a relation in the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}/23\mathbb{Z}$ of integers modulo $23$. Here, $\frac{1}{25}$ is **just a notation** for the multiplicative inverse of the class of $25$ modulo 23 (that is the class of 12). In that point of view, this is not the class of the rational number $\frac{1}{25}$, because this is not even defined !
2. You may see that as a relation in the quotient of a bigger ring than $\mathbb{Z}$ that contains $\frac{1}{25}$. Indeed, denote

$$\mathbb{Z}_{(23)} = \left\{\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}, \, b \textrm{ coprime to } 23\right\}$$

Then you can check this is a ring, and it contains $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{25}$. The good news is the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_{(23)}/23\mathbb{Z}_{(23)}$ is actually isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/23\mathbb{Z}$. This allows you to talk about the class of $\frac{1}{25}$ modulo $23$. There's a small price to pay however : the relation $\frac{1}{25} \equiv \frac{1}{2} \mod 23$ translates to $\frac{1}{25} = \frac{1}{2} + 23 k$ with $k$ being no longer an integer but $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{(23)}$.