# Question on Summation Formula for Fermat Quotients

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

According to Wolfram (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatQuotient.html),

$\displaystyle \frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}$

I am struggling to understand how the sum is derived because the RHS converges to $\frac{1}{2}\ln2$ as $p\rightarrow\infty$. However, Fermat quotients diverge. I would be grateful for any help on this.

Comment: The sums are equal *modulo $p$* where $\frac 1n$ refers to multiplying by the multiplicative inverse of $n$ modulo $p$. The right hand sum is then a modulo $p$ sum, not a sum of real numbers, and there's no question of convergence of such a sum.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How would I write the above equation in modulo notation (i.e. $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}\equiv\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}\pmod{p}$ doesn't seem quite right)?

Comment: Another way of phrasing my question is that I can't see how $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}$ is a multiple of $p$, give that $\forall p \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}\notin\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: That is my point. See, $\frac 1n$ is a quantity modulo $p$. Let me give you an example : what $\frac 13$ modulo $5$? We have that $2 \times 3 = 6 = 1$ modulo $5$, so $2 = \frac 13$  modulo $5$. We then interpret $\frac 13$ as $2$. So they are all integers modulo $p$. Read the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355820/congruence-of-2-fractions-how-to-properly-rewrite-in-terms-without-modulo) for more details. Unfortunately,  the expression you've written in your first comment is right and is probably the way things should be written. We can clarify this with examples.

Comment: So, if we can interpret $\frac{1}{3}$ as $2$ (similar to the idea of an isomorphism), what can the sum be interpreted as (i.e. could the congruence be solved in terms of some $k$)? For example, $\forall a,b,p\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $a\equiv b \pmod{p}$, then $\frac{a-b}{p}\in\mathbb{Z}$. That doesn't apply for when $p$ is not an integer. Sorry, if my questions are tedious but I don't find the concept intuitive.

Comment: I think you are due an answer to this question. I will do my best to provide it in some time. It is not intuitive, so I will add intuition when possible.

Comment: You may see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### The meaning of $\frac1a \pmod m$

The idea behind the notation $\frac 1a$ modulo $m$ comes from ring theory (Please use the Wikipedia pages for groups and rings to get in touch with these concepts). Indeed, the integers $0,...,m-1$ form a group under operation $a + b = c$ where $c$ is the remainder when $a+b$ (the usual sum) is divided by $m$, and under the multiplication operator $a \cdot b =  c$ where $c$ is the remainder when $a\cdot b$ (the usual product) is divided by $m$.

Now, $1$ is called the multiplicative identity , because $a \cdot 1 =a$ for any $a$. In correspondence with group theoretic reasoning, we call an element $a \in \{0,...,m-1\}$ invertible if there is a $b$ such that $a \cdot b = 1$. That is, if there is an integer $b \in \{0,1,...,m-1\}$ such that $a \cdot b$ leaves a remainder of $1$ when divided by $m$.

It can be proven that the inverse, if it exists, is unique. The notation of the inverse of $a$ , if it exists, is either $\frac 1a$ or $a^{-1}$.

Now, there is an easy result for when $a$ is invertible in $\{0,...,m-1\}$ (we call this as invertibility modulo $m$).

> $a$ is invertible if and only if $\gcd(a,m) = 1$.

So $\frac 1a$ is a valid element of $\{0,1,...,m-1\}$ whenever $a$ is coprime to $m$.

> $\textbf{A SMALL CAVEAT}$ : The quantity $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}$ is an *actual division by $p$*. You can see that $\gcd(p,p) = p \neq 1$ so $\frac 1p$ doesn't make sense modulo $p$. That is an actual *division* by $p$. I will show this in my example below. It is an abuse of notation of $\frac{\cdot}{\cdot}$ to represent both actual division and modulo division, and we should be careful of this in general. You can ask if $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}$ will always be an integer : this is true by Fermat's little theorem.

##### Examples

- Let $m=5$ and $a=2$. Then $\gcd(2,5) = 1$ so $\frac 12$ is a well defined element modulo $5$. Can we find it? By experimenting, $2 \cdot 3 = 6$ leaves remainder $1$ upon division by $5$, so $3 = \frac 12$ modulo $5$. In particular, when we are dealing with the ring of integers modulo $5$, and we see $\frac 12$ somewhere, it actually stands for $3$.
- Let $m =15$ and $a = 8$. Then $\gcd(8,15) = 1$ and you can see that $\frac 18 = 2$.
- Let $m = 16$ and $a=10$. Then $\gcd(10,16) \neq 1$ so $\frac 1{10}$ cannot be defined or talked about modulo $16$.
- Let $m$ be a prime, and $a \neq 0$. Then $\gcd(a,m) = 1$ so $\frac 1a$ *always exists*, although one can find it only by experimentation or algorithms like reversing the Euclidean algorithm.

##### On the identity in the question

Thus, what does the identity mean finally? Well, the RHS is *not a real number*, but rather an *integer modulo $p$*. The only way to illustrate this is to actually compute both the sides for a certain prime $p$. We will compute each term separately. Let's go with $p=5$.

- LHS : $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p} = \frac{2^4-1}{5} = 3$, an *actual division, remember the caveat*.
- RHS : We have $\frac 12 = 3$. Then for each of $n=1$ to $4$ we compute $\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$. For $n=1$, $\frac {(-1)^0}{1} = \frac 11 = 1$. Then for $n=2$ we have $\frac{(-1)^1}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}= -3 = 2$. For $n=3$ we have $\frac{(-1)^2}{3} = \frac 13 = 2$. For $n=4$ we have $\frac{(-1)^3}{4} = \frac {-1}4 = -4 = 1$ (since $4\times 4 = 16 = 1$). So the sum finally is $3(1+2+2+1) = 3 \cdot 6 = 18 =3$.

So both RHS and LHS are equal to $3$ modulo $5$. That is how you would read that identity.

##### Historical significance

So what's the fuss about this whole identity? Well, it comes from Fermat's last theorem. Recall the Fermat's last theorem : for every $n \geq 3$ there are no positive integers $x,y,z$ with $x^n+y^n=z^n$.

It is easy to prove that Fermat's last theorem is true if and only if it is true for $n$ taking just prime values, $n>2$. So we can study each prime. While studying each prime, the Fermat quotient comes up, in a way that I can't explain but is illustrative.

Wieferich proved in 1909 that if the FLT was contradicted for $n=p$, then it is necessary that $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}p = 0 \pmod{p}$. That is, we must have that the Fermat quotient for $p$ with base $2$ must be equal to $0$. This generated interest in the identity given because it naturally provided a different way of computing the Fermat quotient.

Only two primes (such primes with Fermat quotient with base $2$ equal to $0$ are called Wieferich primes) are known! They are $1093$ and $3511$.

The result does not stay true for only base $2$ : it was later extended to all prime bases up to $89$. That is : if there is a counterexample of FLT for $n=p$ then the Fermat quotient of $p$ with base $k$ must be zero for all primes $k$ from $2$ to $89$! If only we could show that no such prime existed, we'd be done, but this has been elusive.

##### Proof of the identity

The proof of the identity is not easy, because it involves some manipulations that you will not be able to get at first glance. So I will not include it here. Instead, I will ask you to visit the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951006/about-the-fermat-quotients-with-base-2), which goes through the proof of a very similar identity. You can attempt to use the proof there to prove this.

The main idea is to get yourself comfortable with arithmetic modulo $p$. This is necessary before you can understand the above identity.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. To be clear, $\frac{1}{2}$ maps to $3$, $\frac{1}{3}\rightarrow 2$, $\frac{1}{4}\rightarrow 4$ modulo $5$. How would one define a general operation for some $\frac{1}{a}\rightarrow k$? It seems that $1\equiv ak \pmod{5}$ is one option, but this implies that $\frac{1}{2}$ maps to $3,8,13,3+5n$ etc. I assume that it is the first multiple (i.e. when $n$ is $0$), but how would this be mathematically defined?

Comment: @UNOwen Yes, it is defined as the unique member of $\{0,...,m-1\}$ which works. So for example, even though $\frac 12$ modulo $5$ could be any of $3,-2,-7,8,13$ and so on (multiplying each of these with $2$ leads to a number which has remainder $1$ when divided by $5$), only $3$ lies between $0$ and $5$, so we take $\frac 12 = 3$.